# Cordova/PhoneGap FileTransfer Uploaded File Doesn't Appear on Server

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

I am building an app using Cordova (CLI) to upload a file and the location that it was taken at to a server. So far the only thing that doesn't work is uploading the file to the server. The file upload seems to work fine, but the POST data never shows up at the server.

Here is the code used to upload:

```
function uploadToServer () {
    bootstrap_alert("Uploading!","Please do not close PowerSnap.", "info") // Could bootstrap be causing any trouble?
    $('#uploadButton').button('loading'); //Sets the upload button to loading state

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = 'file.jpg';
    options.mimeType= "image/jpeg";
    options.headers={'Connection':'close'};
    var params = {};
    params.command = "upload";
    params.coordinates = locationTextBox.value;

    options.params = params;

    uriToUpload = uploadFileEntry.toURL();
    var ft;
    ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(uriToUpload, encodeURI('http://url.removed.com'), uploadSuccess, uploadError, options, true); // The PHP script is named index.php so the server knows to redirect to it.
}
```

The logcat seems to indicate that it works.

```
D/FileTransfer( 8014): upload cdvfile://localhost/temporary/1393131949448.jpg to http://powersnap.7katz.com
D/FileTransfer( 8014): fileKey: file
D/FileTransfer( 8014): fileName: file.jpg
D/FileTransfer( 8014): mimeType: image/jpeg
D/FileTransfer( 8014): params: {"command":"upload","coordinates":"(Omitted, but functioning properly"}
D/FileTransfer( 8014): trustEveryone: true
D/FileTransfer( 8014): chunkedMode: true
D/FileTransfer( 8014): headers: {"Connection":"close"}
D/FileTransfer( 8014): objectId: 1
D/FileTransfer( 8014): httpMethod: POST
D/FileTransfer( 8014): Content Length: 2486171
D/FileTransfer( 8014): Uploaded 114958 of 2486171 bytes
D/FileTransfer( 8014): Uploaded 229646 of 2486171 bytes
D/FileTransfer( 8014): Uploaded 344334 of 2486171 bytes
D/FileTransfer( 8014): Uploaded 459022 of 2486171 bytes
D/FileTransfer( 8014): Uploaded 573710 of 2486171 bytes
```

This continues for a few seconds, then eventually it gets to:

```
D/FileTransfer( 8014): Sent 2486171 of 2486171
D/FileTransfer( 8014): response code: 200
D/FileTransfer( 8014): response headers: {null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Connection=[close], Content-Type=[application/json], Date=[Sun, 23 Feb 2014 05:06:17 GMT], OkHttp-Received-Millis=[1393131977469], OkHttp-Response-Source=[NETWORK 200], OkHttp-Selected-Transport=[http/1.1], OkHttp-Sent-Millis=[1393131977136], Server=[Apache], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked]}
D/FileTransfer( 8014): got response from server
D/FileTransfer( 8014): Error
```

The last line (`D/FileTransfer( 8014): Error`) is the response from the server after a PHP switch, indicating that the server didn't get the params. (The access.log on the server shows that the app has connected) When I have the server log the `$_FILES` or `$_POST` to a file, the file is created if it doesn't exist and is blank. I have tested the PHP script that receives the files using Advanced Rest Client for Chrome, and the script works as intended. Thank you for any help, and sorry if this question is unclear.

Comment: Did you enabled CORS on the server? Normally the httpmethod should be OPTIONS

Comment: I enabled it on the server, but it didn't do anything, and Cordova doesn't appear to need CORS. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19594972/2142180

Comment: I had some problems with this too. I solved it by using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use that, but it seems a little more complex than the fileTransfer from Cordova.

Comment: Thank you, that worked very well for me. It even has a tutorial on how to implement MySql into the upload script.